# deconstructing basic Tk inter script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need help in understanding how Tk inter works.I'm using the first example from the documents page which creates a simple window with 2 buttons.
[Introduction to GUI programming with tkinter](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html)

Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Questions:

- MyFirstGUI does not inherit from TK or Frame so how does it know of all the parameters (self.label,self.greet etc) one might find in the Tk class
- We are passing a TK object to the variable root ( root = Tk() )
  and passing that into MyFirstGUI class (my_gui = MyFirst GUI(root) )
  .The only plausible explanation then, is that  self.label and  self.greet_button are "indeed" class variables to begin with and "become" labels ( and buttons ) once they are bound with functions such as Label(master,text="This is our first GUI!")

is my understanding correct ?

behram

Answer (score 0):

So tkinter is just a library with classes inside of it, in this code you are importing the TK class, the Label class, and the Button class. When you use import statements at the top of your code, you are telling the computer to go fetch those files/functions and read them into the program. For example, if the TK class is say 100 lines of code, the statement
`from tkinter import TK` is equivalent to those 100 lines of code being in front of what you have written.

Now jumping to the creation of the UI itself, you create an instance of the TK class, and assign it to the variable root.
This root creates the outer window you will see when you run your UI, it holds the title, the min/max/close buttons in the top right corner, and determines the size of the window, along with a bunch of other features.
"root" is just a conventional name, it could be "potato" but as long as you know that is the foundation of your User Interface, that's what matters.
It won't be called too much outside of that first time you pass it into your class unless you're doing a lot of window manipulation.

From there, you are passing that root (window) to your MyFirstGUI object.
The `__init__` function will run at the time of creation for any python class and the parameters for that function will be the parameters required to call the class. In this case, there are two parameters self, and master.

"self" is required as the first parameter of all functions inside a class so that the function knows the object it belongs to and so that it can access the class level variables available to it.
"master" has a default value of None so you could theoretically call `MyFirstGUI()` but in this case we are passing the root (window) as the master for the object `MyFirstGUI(root)`.

At that point, because we are creating an instance of MyFirstGUI, `__init__` fires and the first thing it does is sets self.master equal to the input of master so that it can be referenced anywhere in the object, expanding the scope beyond just the `__init__` function.

From there, the function is arbitrarily defining variables that are scoped at the class level by using `self.` again so that these variables can be called from any part of this class.
`self.label` is just a name the original writer decided on, once again it could be `self.macaroni` as long as it makes sense to you that this is your label.
Then, because you have imported the Label class from tkinter, you are able to just refer to it as if it was already in your code. When you call these classes, they return the objects that are being set to your `self.label` so that you can refer to them later in the program.

If you check out the docs, you can see the Label and Button classes each have their own set of parameters available to them.
Common parameters include as you see "text" to show text that you'd like it to have, command to let a button know which function it should fire when clicked, "width" to determine the width of the widget on screen, and so on.

With the use of Default values, you don't always need to provide every single possible parameter to a call to create these objects.
Deciding what parameters to give comes down to practice and knowledge of the capabilities of each class in order to know which values you want to set and what are appropriate settings for them.

tldr:

1. Your import statements at the top allow you to use the classes at will, and your knowledge determines which parameters to send to each class. The docs are your friend!
2. I believe your understanding is correct. `self.label` is defined in the `__init__` function by the programmer, and then assigned the widget object of a tkLabel by calling the class. From that point on, `self.label` is available anywhere inside the MyFirstGUI class to be manipulated as you see fit. For example, instead of the `greet` function printing out "Greetings!" you could change that print statement to `self.label.set("Greetings!")` so now your button click will change the label's text instead.

I hope this helped!